# Firefox on Ubunto 20.11 opens new page insted of new tab

Tags: firefox

Recently installed Ubuntu 20.11 when a link is clicked on **Firefox** it sometimes opens a **new page** and not a **new link**. This happens even if I ask to be opened in a new link.

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu 20.10 - or 22.10 (like your other question)?

Comment: Don't post the same question multiple times, stick to one post please, and *edit* the original if you have more info to add.

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format; with 2000 being subtracted from the year, so 20.11 would mean 2020-November (20.11) release,where no release occurred that month.